# Building cross compiler: pthread.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I'm currently trying to compile my own gcc 9.1.0 cross compiler for `aarch64-linux-gnu` target. I used this tutorial: https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

The compile progress for the gcc and g++ compiler seems to finish without errors, but allways when I try to compile `libgcc` with the command `make all-target-libgcc` I run into this error:

```
In file included from ../../../gcc-9.1.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148,
                 from ../../../gcc-9.1.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:10: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include <pthread.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

`g++ --version` on my build maschine prints:

```
g++ (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And my configuration command for `gcc` is:
`../gcc-9.1.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --without-headers`
With:

```
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-gnu
export PREFIX=/opt/aarch64-linux-gnu
```

What do I forget?

Comment: `pthread.h` is a glibc header, provided by the package glibc-devel / libc6-dev .... package name depending on which OS you are using.

Comment: And why pthread isn't found? The `pthread.h` should be in the gcc build tree or not? I mean I'm able to find it with `find`.

Comment: Shall the compiler use the build's `pthread.h` or the host's `pthread.h`?

Answer (score 2):

From GCC installation manual:

> In order to build GCC, the C standard library and headers must be
>    present for all target variants for which target libraries will be
>    built (and not only the variant of the host C++ compiler).

So you need a libc for aarch64.

If you want to build it yourself, Preshing has a good [article](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) on the topic, which I haven't read in full but recommend anyway. He even has a picture mentioning both `pthread.h` and `libgcc.a`.

AFAIK, GCC can pick up a symlink to `newlib` sources and build it automatically during the course of building a full cross compiler with target libraries. Not sure about Glibc.